# Phaser tilemap shows extra lines on Firefox

Tags: phaser-framework

My phaser game has the following settings

```
import Phaser from 'phaser'
import GameScene from './scenes/GameScene'

const config = {
  type: Phaser.CANVAS,
  parent: 'game-content',
  backgroundColor: '#123456',
  pixelArt: true, // Prevent pixel art from becoming blurred when scaledpixelArt: true, // Prevent pixel art from becoming blurred when scaled
  scale: {
    mode: Phaser.Scale.ScaleModes.RESIZE,
    width: window.innerWidth,
    height: window.innerHeight,
  },
  physics: {
    default: 'arcade',
    arcade: {
      gravity: { y: 0, x: 0 },
    },
  },
  scene: [GameScene],
}

export const phaserGame = new Phaser.Game(config)
```

When I open my game on Google Chrome or Safari on desktop, there are no extra lines shown on my tilemap

[image]

But when I open my game on Firefox on desktop, extra lines are shown on my tilemap

[image]

Has anyone else experience this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Disclaimer never used this tool***
I never had this issue, but there some artikel showing how to solve this with a tool called ***Tile Extruder*** *(here the links [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62936847/how-do-i-stop-my-tiles-from-bleeding-when-using-a-tilemap-in-phaser-3), [link2](https://phaser.discourse.group/t/tilemap-gaps-when-camera-moves/1162))*

I personally don't like using external tool, so I would opt, to change the settings of you `tilemap`, and making the tiles `1 px` smaller on each side, and adjusting the tile margin *(with the properties `tileWidth`,`tileHeight` and `tileMargin`)*.
This workaround won't work for every tileset.

> *Sadly there are some differences in how browser render objects canvas.*